# Name of "functions" class is not as per java naming convention

Tags: java, apache-spark, naming-conventions

While going through documentation of Apache Spark for Java language, I encountered a class `functions` under package `org.apache.spark.sql` which does not conform to standard java naming conventions of a class name.
Does this class name, in all lower case letters, represents a special scenario or could it be a typo?

documentation link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html

[image: screenshot]

Comment: No, it is not a typo, it is called `functions`, end of story. Why? Maybe because it only has `static` members anyway and accessing them via `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.someFunction` looks cleaner than `org.apache.spark.sql.Functions.someFunction`.

Comment: @luk2302 I actually find it less clean than if the name had simply followed conventions.

Comment: A naming convention is just ... a naming convention. You can name the classes as you like. If classes could not be named lowercase it would be blocked by the language specification itself.

Comment: @Avneet Naming conventions are just that—conventions. They don't have to be followed. It could be a typo and now they can't fix it due to backwards compatibility, it could be as luk2302 described and the authors thought it looked cleaner, or it could be some other reason.

Comment: @Slaw ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I agree it makes the import look cleaner. I was confused because java already has classes for e.g. `Files` in `java.nio.file` package with all static methods and still conforming to naming conventions. But I agree, it could be a design decision to name `functions` class with all lower case.

Answer (score 2):

It's a design decision and not a typo.

All functions of class `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` are `static` and probably only will be used with a static import.

For example:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.abs;
```

and will be directly referenced in code like `abs(col("columnName"));`

---

On the other hand, (as discussed in the comments) a naming convention is just a guideline to follow. Naming (caps, Camel or snake case) does not change the semantics of the code.

Comment: Just to make it clear, this functionality is not affected by the name of the class in any way; if the class was named `Functions` it could still be statically imported without issue.